# change a bitmap's pixel colour

Tags: image, delphi

I am trying to change a bit-map's pixel color if it's white. I wrote following code. But it's awfully slow!. i want to check if a pixel's color is white or not, and if it is white, change the color to black.

Can anybody suggest a better approach?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BitMap1 : TBitmap;
  X, Y, Size : Integer;

  P: Cardinal;
begin
  BitMap1 := TBitmap.Create;
  bitMap1.LoadFromFile('image1.bmp');

  for Y := 0 to Bitmap1.Height - 1 do
  begin
    for X := 0 to Bitmap1.width  * size - 1 do
    begin
    p := BitMap1.Canvas.Pixels[X,Y];
    if p = 255 then
      BitMap1.Canvas.Pixels[X,Y] := 0;

    end;
  end;

  Image1.Picture.Assign(BitMap1);
end;
```

Comment: For the fast access to bitmap pixels use the `ScanLine` property. You might find something to read e.g. [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13583451/960757).

Comment: @TLama Wonderful tutorial. Thanks a lot

Comment: There are a few issues with your code. First, `X` should only go to `Bitmap1.Width - 1`. Second, the white colour is `clWhite`, which is `16777215`, not `255`. (Third, you forgot to `Free` the bitmap.) [And some minor points: `p` should preferably be `TColor` and `0` should preferably be `clBlack`.]

Comment: Ah, the scourge of Canvas.Pixels[] strikes again!

Comment: @dthorpe, Embarcadero should add a compiler warning when using it in loop :-)

Comment: @tlama Embarcadero should mark it as obsolete so any use will generate a warning.

Comment: @dthorpe, I wouldn't call it obsolete. There are situations where it's still sufficient. For instance if you'd need to implement image color picker.

Comment: @tlama It should be harder to shoot oneself in the foot. Canvas.Pixels[] is a bear trap because it's deceptively simple to use but carries a horrific performance penalty. I'm in favor of marking Canvas.Pixels[] with a deprecated or obsolete attribute. I'm never in favor of adding special case code to the compiler to warn about use of a bad function. That turns the compiler code into an episode of "Hoarders" - accumulation of special cases forever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use scanlines for this. Example:

```
procedure ChangeWhiteToBlack(var Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  scanline: PRGBTriple;
  y: Integer;
  x: Integer;
begin
  Assert(Bitmap.PixelFormat = pf24bit);
  for y := 0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    scanline := Bitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to Bitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      with scanline^ do
      begin
        if (rgbtBlue = 255) and (rgbtGreen = 255) and (rgbtRed = 255) then
          FillChar(scanline^, sizeof(TRGBTriple), 0);
      end;
      inc(scanline);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

To try this:

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  bm: TBitmap;
begin
  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bm.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\test.bmp');
    ChangeWhiteToBlack(bm);
    bm.SaveToFile('C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\test2.bmp');
  finally
    bm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Update:** You need only a very minor modification of the code to make it work on 32-bit bitmaps instead:

```
procedure ChangeWhiteToBlack32(var Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  scanline: PRGBQuad;
  y: Integer;
  x: Integer;
begin
  Assert(Bitmap.PixelFormat = pf32bit);
  for y := 0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    scanline := Bitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to Bitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      with scanline^ do
      begin
        if (rgbBlue = 255) and (rgbGreen = 255) and (rgbRed = 255) then
          FillChar(scanline^, sizeof(TRGBQuad), 0);
      end;
      inc(scanline);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

In fact, you could do

```
procedure ChangeWhiteToBlack24(var Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  scanline: PRGBTriple;
  y: Integer;
  x: Integer;
begin
  Assert(Bitmap.PixelFormat = pf24bit);
  for y := 0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    scanline := Bitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to Bitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      with scanline^ do
      begin
        if (rgbtBlue = 255) and (rgbtGreen = 255) and (rgbtRed = 255) then
          FillChar(scanline^, sizeof(TRGBTriple), 0);
      end;
      inc(scanline);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure ChangeWhiteToBlack32(var Bitmap: TBitmap);
var
  scanline: PRGBQuad;
  y: Integer;
  x: Integer;
begin
  Assert(Bitmap.PixelFormat = pf32bit);
  for y := 0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    scanline := Bitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to Bitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      with scanline^ do
      begin
        if (rgbBlue = 255) and (rgbGreen = 255) and (rgbRed = 255) then
          FillChar(scanline^, sizeof(TRGBQuad), 0);
      end;
      inc(scanline);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure ChangeWhiteToBlack(var Bitmap: TBitmap);
begin
  case Bitmap.PixelFormat of
    pf24bit: ChangeWhiteToBlack24(Bitmap);
    pf32bit: ChangeWhiteToBlack32(Bitmap);
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Pixel format must be pf24bit or pf32bit.');
  end;
end;
```

if you don't want to make a single procedure that works with both 24-bit and 32-bit bitmaps, as `TLama` did. [One benefit of having two separate procedures is that these short procedures are easier to read (and maintain).]

Comment: @jimsweb: No. But the change required to adapt it to the 32-bit case is very minor.

Answer (score 12):

For sure use the [`ScanLine`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.ScanLine) property to access bitmap pixels since you're working with a large array of pixels where the [`Pixels`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.Pixels) access is slow. For replacing colors of your choice with support for 24-bit and 32-bit bitmaps, I would use something like this:

```delphi
procedure ReplaceColor(ABitmap: TBitmap; ASource, ATarget: TColor);
type
  TRGBBytes = array[0..2] of Byte;
var
  I: Integer;
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  Size: Integer;
  Pixels: PByteArray;
  SourceColor: TRGBBytes;
  TargetColor: TRGBBytes;
const
  TripleSize = SizeOf(TRGBBytes);
begin
  case ABitmap.PixelFormat of
    pf24bit: Size := TripleSize;
    pf32bit: Size := SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Bitmap must be 24-bit or 32-bit format!');
  end;

  for I := 0 to TripleSize - 1 do
  begin
    // fill the array of bytes with color channel values in BGR order,
    // the same would do for the SourceColor from ASource parameter:
    // SourceColor[0] := GetBValue(ASource);
    // SourceColor[1] := GetGValue(ASource);
    // SourceColor[2] := GetRValue(ASource);
    // but this is (just badly readable) one liner
    SourceColor[I] := Byte(ASource shr (16 - (I * 8)));
    // the same do for the TargetColor array from the ATarget parameter
    TargetColor[I] := Byte(ATarget shr (16 - (I * 8)));
  end;

  for Y := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    // get a pointer to the currently iterated row pixel byte array
    Pixels := ABitmap.ScanLine[Y];
    // iterate the row horizontally pixel by pixel
    for X := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      // now imagine, that you have an array of bytes in which the groups of
      // bytes represent a single pixel - e.g. the used Pixels array for the
      // first 2 pixels might look like this for 24-bit and 32-bit bitmaps:

      // Pixels   [0][1][2]     [3][4][5]
      // 24-bit    B  G  R       B  G  R
      // Pixels   [0][1][2][3]  [4][5][6][7]
      // 32-bit    B  G  R  A    B  G  R  A

      // from the above you can see that you'll need to multiply the current
      // pixel iterator by the count of color channels to point to the first
      // (blue) color channel in that array; and that's what that (X * Size)
      // is for here; X is a pixel iterator, Size is size of a single pixel:          

      // X * 3    (0 * 3)       (1 * 3)
      //           ⇓             ⇓
      // Pixels   [0][1][2]     [3][4][5]
      // 24-bit    B  G  R       B  G  R

      // X * 4    (0 * 4)       (1 * 4)
      //           ⇓             ⇓
      // Pixels   [0][1][2][3]  [4][5][6][7]
      // 32-bit    B  G  R  A    B  G  R  A

      // so let's compare a BGR value starting at the (X * Size) position of
      // the Pixels array with the SourceColor array and if it matches we've
      // found the same colored pixel, if so then...
      if CompareMem(@Pixels[(X * Size)], @SourceColor, TripleSize) then
        // copy the TargetColor color byte array values to that BGR position
        // (in other words, replace the color channel bytes there)
        Move(TargetColor, Pixels[(X * Size)], TripleSize);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And the usage:

```delphi
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile('d:\Image.bmp');
    ReplaceColor(Bitmap, clWhite, clBlack);
    Image1.Picture.Assign(Bitmap);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

For pure GDI and bitmaps having at most 256 colors you might use the [`CreateMappedBmp`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Graphics.CreateMappedBmp) function.

Comment: This only works if the bitmap is 24-bit, of course. You should probably include an `Assert`, at least.

Answer (score 1):

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BitMap1,
  BitMap2 : TBitmap;
  X, Y, Size : Integer;

  P: Cardinal;
begin
  BitMap1 := TBitmap.Create;
  BitMap1.LoadFromFile('image1.bmp');
  BitMap1.Transparent := true;
  BitMap1.TransparentColor := clWhite; // old color

  BitMap2 := TBitMap.Create;
  BitMap2.Height := BitMap1.Height;
  BitMap2.Width := BitMap1.Width;
  BitMap2.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack; // new color
  BitMap2.Canvas.FillRect(
   Rect(
     0,
     0,
     BitMap2.Width,
     BitMap2.Height
    )
  );
 
  BitMap2.Canvas.Draw(BitMap1);
  
  Image1.Picture.Assign(BitMap2);
  
  BitMap1.Free;
  BitMap2.Freel
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void btnLoad2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap myBitmap= new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        Bitmap myBitmap1 = new Bitmap("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Lalji\\Desktop\\image.png");
        for (int x = 0; x < myBitmap.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < myBitmap.Height; y++)
            {
                // Get the color of a pixel within myBitmap.
                Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                string pixelColorStringValue =
                    pixelColor.R.ToString("D3") + " " +
                    pixelColor.G.ToString("D3") + " " +
                    pixelColor.B.ToString("D3") + ", ";
                if (pixelColor.R.Equals(0) && pixelColor.G.Equals(0) && pixelColor.B.Equals(0))
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("black pixel");
                }

                else if (pixelColor.R.Equals(255) && pixelColor.G.Equals(255) && pixelColor.B.Equals(255))
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("white pixel");
                    myBitmap1.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                }
                //switch (pixelColorStringValue)
                //{
                //    case "255 255 255":
                //        {
                //            // white pixel
                //            MessageBox.Show("white pixel");
                //            break;
                //        }
                //    case "000 000 000,":
                //        {
                //            // black pixel
                //           MessageBox.Show("black pixel");
                //            break;
                //        }
                //}
            }
        }

        myBitmap1.Save("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Lalji\\Desktop\\image1.png");
        MessageBox.Show("Process done");
    }
```