# Convert image to matrix

Tags: image, delphi, matrix, bmp

I am trying to convert an image (lets say black and white) to a Matrix (where 0 = black and 1 = white)

i tried with this code :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  tab = array[1..1000,1..1000] of byte;
var i,j: integer;
    s : string;
    image : TBitmap;
    t : tab;
begin
  image := TBitmap.Create;
  image.LoadFromFile('c:\image.bmp');

  s := '';
  for i := 0 to image.Height do
  begin
     for j := 0 to image.Width do
     begin
      if image.Canvas.Pixels[i,j] = clWhite then
        t[i,j] := 0
      else
        t[i,j] := 1;

     end;
  end;
  for i := 0 to image.Height do
  begin
    for j := 0 to image.Width do
     begin
      s:=s + IntToStr(t[i,j]);
     end;
     Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
     s:='';
  end;
end;
```

But it gave me wrong results.

Any Idea?

Comment: Nooo, `Pixels` are back again.

Comment: what ?? what am i doing wrong here??!

Comment: It will be terribly slow... You should use `TBitmap.ScanLine` property when you're accessing large area of pixels.

Comment: well i dont care about it being slow or fast, and all the images im using are > 100 width and heiht

Comment: @Roro: Except for the three obvious bugs, as pointed out in my answer.

Comment: @yassine_hell : "what ?? what am i doing wrong here??!" you must looping width first. Pixels[i,j] = Pixels[x,y]

Comment: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here." Well, I'm pretty sure it's "What is the problem with the code?". "...cannot be reasonably answered in its current form" So neither my nor TLama's answer is good? "Ambigious, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or thetorical"? Really? I don't think so.

Comment: Why was this question closed? Seems like a valid one.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a personal debugging service, @Leonardo. The question essentially says "Please debug my code for me." The close reason I'd have chosen, had I seen this before, would have been *too localized*.

Comment: @RobKennedy: I agree on that one. (So casperOne sure chose the wrong reason.) But still, if someone actually is nice enough to do the debugging (hm... like myself, in this case), I think its OK. In addition, discussion about good and bad coding techniques might be useful even to third parties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following procedure converts the input `ABitmap` bitmap to a multidimensional `AMatrix` array of bytes, which represents pixels and where 0 value means white pixel and 1 means any other color:

```
type
  TPixelMatrix = array of array of Byte;

procedure BitmapToMatrix(ABitmap: TBitmap; var AMatrix: TPixelMatrix);
type
  TRGBBytes = array[0..2] of Byte;
var
  I: Integer;
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  Size: Integer;
  Pixels: PByteArray;
  SourceColor: TRGBBytes;
const
  TripleSize = SizeOf(TRGBBytes);
begin
  case ABitmap.PixelFormat of
    pf24bit: Size := SizeOf(TRGBTriple);
    pf32bit: Size := SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
  else
    raise Exception.Create('ABitmap must be 24-bit or 32-bit format!');
  end;

  SetLength(AMatrix, ABitmap.Height, ABitmap.Width);
  for I := 0 to TripleSize - 1 do
    SourceColor[I] := Byte(clWhite shr (16 - (I * 8)));

  for Y := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    Pixels := ABitmap.ScanLine[Y];
    for X := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      if CompareMem(@Pixels[(X * Size)], @SourceColor, TripleSize) then
        AMatrix[Y, X] := 0
      else
        AMatrix[Y, X] := 1;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This procedure prints out the multidimensional `AMatrix` array of bytes to the `AMemo` memo box:

```
procedure ShowPixelMatrix(AMemo: TMemo; const AMatrix: TPixelMatrix);
var
  S: string;
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
begin
  AMemo.Clear;
  AMemo.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    AMemo.Lines.Add('Matrix size: ' + IntToStr(Length(AMatrix[0])) + 'x' +
      IntToStr(Length(AMatrix)));
    AMemo.Lines.Add('');

    for Y := 0 to High(AMatrix) do
    begin
      S := '';
      for X := 0 to High(AMatrix[Y]) - 1 do
      begin
        S := S + IntToStr(AMatrix[Y, X]);
      end;
      AMemo.Lines.Add(S);
    end;
  finally
    AMemo.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

And the usage of the above procedures:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  PixelMatrix: TPixelMatrix;
begin
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile('d:\Image.bmp');
    BitmapToMatrix(Bitmap, PixelMatrix);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
  ShowPixelMatrix(Memo1, PixelMatrix);
end;
```

This extension of the above `BitmapToMatrix` procedure allows you to specify at which [`luminance`](http://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bt/R-REC-BT.601-6-200701-S!!PDF-E.pdf#page=2) level given by the `AMinIntensity` parameter will be pixels taken as non-white.

The more the `AMinIntensity` value is closer to 0, the more lighter pixels are treated as non-white. This allows you to work with a color intensity tolerance (e.g. to better recognize antialiased text):

```
procedure BitmapToMatrixEx(ABitmap: TBitmap; var AMatrix: TPixelMatrix;
  AMinIntensity: Byte);
type
  TRGBBytes = array[0..2] of Byte;
var
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  Gray: Byte;
  Size: Integer;
  Pixels: PByteArray;
begin
  case ABitmap.PixelFormat of
    pf24bit: Size := SizeOf(TRGBTriple);
    pf32bit: Size := SizeOf(TRGBQuad);
  else
    raise Exception.Create('ABitmap must be 24-bit or 32-bit format!');
  end;

  SetLength(AMatrix, ABitmap.Height, ABitmap.Width);

  for Y := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    Pixels := ABitmap.ScanLine[Y];
    for X := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      Gray := 255 - Round((0.299 * Pixels[(X * Size) + 2]) +
        (0.587 * Pixels[(X * Size) + 1]) + (0.114 * Pixels[(X * Size)]));

      if Gray < AMinIntensity then
        AMatrix[Y, X] := 0
      else
        AMatrix[Y, X] := 1;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Note that the above code is untested written just in browser... I'll review it later (I hope).

Comment: If the image is black/white, it might actually be 1-bit! And if it is, it is even easier to convert it to a byte/textual matrix.

Comment: @yassine_hell, what pixel formats so you need to support for this ? Are your bitmaps 1-bit as Andreas think ? If so, what other pixel formats do you need to work with ?

Comment: no i guess its 32bits, because i'm actually dealing with white background and light blue text. i just mentioned black and white to make it easier to understand

Comment: (Most BMPs are 24-bit.)

Comment: Thank you, your code worked like a charm :) and actually i was doing a small captcha solver, it consist at converting an image to 0's and 1's then extract each letter :) thank you anyways ^^
here s the result http://i48.tinypic.com/xmibr5.png

Comment: @yassine_hell, you're welcome! Although, for your intention I would probably count with some gray tolerance as all captchas (at least which I've seen) have antialised text and using this way can make you to read the text more difficult. I would personally mark in that matrix only pixels having some minimal color intensity.

Comment: well thank god the captcha i'm dealing with is not that hard, only white background and blue text.

Comment: It's quite easy to do so. You can calculate e.g. luminance for each pixel and if it's higher than a specified value, add it to the matrix as 1, otherwise as 0. I'll post an update in few minutes just out of curiosity.

Comment: lol ok have fun, and if you're interested here is the captcha i'm dealing with http://www.ocard.com.tn/jeu_ocard/captcha/captcha.php (if i can post external links)

Comment: I don't like captcha solvers. @yassine_hell: Are you sure your application is legitimate? Are you sure the owners of the web site (http://www.ocard.com.tn/) want their system to be hacked?

Comment: no i'm not hacking, actually i'm helping then for free lol, and we are contacting by phone, they just added the captcha (after i found out a way to spam their DB) now i wana prove that their captcha is week.

Answer (score 12):

There are five bugs and two other issues in your code!

**First**,

```
for i := 0 to image.Height do
```

must be replaced by

```
for i := 0 to image.Height - 1 do
```

(why?) and similarly,

```
for j := 0 to image.Width do
```

must be replaced by

```
for j := 0 to image.Width - 1 do
```

**Second**, the `Pixels` array takes arguments `[x, y]`, not `[y, x]`. Hence, you need to replace

```
image.Canvas.Pixels[i,j]
```

by

```
image.Canvas.Pixels[j,i]
```

**Third**, you wrote "0 = black and 1 = white" but obviously you do the opposite!

**Fourth**, you try to access `t[0, 0]`, even though your matrix starts indexing at `1`. Use `array[0..1000,0..1000] of byte;` to fix that.

**Fifth**, you have a memory leak (`image` isn't freed -- use `try..finally`).

**Also**, it is better to use dynamic arrays:

```
type
  TByteMatrix = array of array of byte;

var
  mat: TByteMatrix;
```

and you begin with

```
SetLength(mat, image.Height - 1, image.Width - 1);
```

if you want it to index `[y, x]`, and opposite otherwise.

**Finally**, you should not use the `Pixels` property at all in this case, since it is terribly slow. Instead, use the `Scanline` property. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297320/change-a-bitmaps-pixel-colour) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583451/how-to-use-scanline-property-for-24-bit-bitmaps) or [something else](http://www.google.se/search?q=Delphi+scanline&aq=f&oq=Delphi+scanline&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for more information.

Also, you will gain a lot of speed simply by adding `Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate` before and `Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate` after the update of the memo control.

Answer (score -1):

Memo lines position is decline, but your looping image.height first its will be result reverse in memo, to that try this code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i,j: integer;
    s : string;
    image : TBitmap;
begin
  image := TBitmap.Create;
  image.LoadFromFile('c:\image.bmp');

  s := '';
  for i := 0 to image.width-1 do
  begin
     for j := 0 to image.Height-1 do
     begin
      if image.Canvas.Pixels[i,j] = clWhite then
        s := s+'0'
      else
        s := s+'1';
     end;
     memo1.Lines.Add(s);
     s:='';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: (1) out of bounds. (2) white = 0? (3) memory leak [Also: no begin/end update?]

Comment: my answer have tested in my pc. and the memo view same with image.bitmap. if that code to slow please change to scanline

Comment: Well, the out of bounds error is obvious! Personally, I prefer code that is guaranteed to work, rather than code that might almost work with some luck. *Update:* that's better.

Comment: oh sory about that i forget to add -1

Comment: @Andreas : for (2) white = 0?, its simple way only change for integer to string, please look the final result that he want

Comment: Yeah, buy the first line of the OP's question is "I am trying to convert an image (lets say black and white) to a Matrix (**where 0 = black and 1 = white**)" (my emphasis). Anyhow, I'm more concerned about the memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for your submission and now I'm getting more knowledge about delphi