# Why does calling GetMem lead to a memory leak?

Tags: delphi

i have this code to see if my foreground window is SDImainframe.

```
Function Active_window_mf() :Boolean;
var
  FromClass: PChar;
begin

  MFhandle := GetForeGroundWindow;
  GetMem(FromClass, 100);
  GetClassName(MFhandle, PChar(FromClass), 800);
  if StrPas(FromClass) = 'SDIMainFrame' then
    result := true;
end;
```

However, MADExcept reports that Getmem function has issues. Could anyone suggest, what is wrong in my code?

Comment: This question amounts to asking why allocating memory leads to a leak.

Comment: Surely `MFhandle` should be a local variable, it you really need to use a variable at all...

Comment: I would do it [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/G9M6JHHF). @Andreas, increase your `CN` to be 256 + NULL terminator long. Class name can be at most 256 chars long, but [`GetClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx) function requires a buffer which can include also NULL terminator.

Comment: I am not sure the question is *that* bad that it need to be closed. After all, beginners might actually believe that the memory allocated by `GetMem` is freed automatically.

Comment: Thanks, @TLama, I wasn't sure if you included the NUL in that restriction. But shouldn't `nMaxCount` be 257, then? The documentation says `The length of the lpClassName buffer, in characters.` Maybe 'characters' means 'non-NUL characters'. And of course you should check for errors.

Comment: @TLama: I see from your (now deleted) post that you believe `257` to be the appropriate value?

Comment: @Andreas, yes. 256 for maximum length of a class name and 1 for NULL terminator. I seriously don't get why this question is going to be closed...

Comment: @TLama: Probably a too 'stupid' question.

Comment: @TLama: I also was somewhat annoyed by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312874/convert-image-to-matrix)

Comment: @jimsweb Don't mix calling a Windows API function and checking whether the class name equals `'SDIMainFrame'`. Write a function that receives an `HWND` parameter and returns a `string` containing the class name. You can write that function exactly once. From then on in you can call it and get back a nicely wrapped up Delphi `string`. It's really important to code at the right abstraction level.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are three problems in your code. **First**, if you allocate memory (`GetMem`), you need to free it (`FreeMem`):

```
GetMem(p, 1024);
try
  // Do sth with the memory
finally
  FreeMem(p);
end;
```

**Second**, I don't see the relation between `100` and `800`. In fact, you lie. You allocate a buffer of 100 bytes, and then you tell Windows that it is big enough to hold 800 Unicode characters.

**Third**, the return value of the function is undefined, unless the comparison is true. Hence, you need either to add `result := false` to the beginning of the procedure, or replace the two last lines (before `end;`) by

```
result := string(FromClass) = 'SDIMainFrame'
```

Anyhow, it's better not to use `GetMem` at all. I'd do it like this:

```
var
  CN: array[0..256] of char;
begin
  GetClassName(MFhandle, CN, 256)
```

Also, you should check for errors. If `GetClassName` returns `0`, an error occurred. Hence, you could do something like

```
function Active_window_mf(): boolean;
var
  CN: array[0..256] of char;
begin
  result := false;
  if GetClassName(GetForegroundWindow, CN, 257) > 0 then
    result := string(CN) = 'SDIMainFrame';
end;
```

**Update:** According to David's excellent point about abstraction levels, it would be nice to do it like this:

```
function ClassNameFromHWND(const Handle: HWND): string;
var
  CN: array[0..256] of char;
begin
  result := '';
  if GetClassName(Handle, CN, 257) > 0 then
    result := CN;
end;

function Active_window_mf(): boolean;
begin
  result := ClassNameFromHWND(GetForegroundWindow) = 'SDIMainForm';
end;
```